# How can I do a nested condition on a has_many in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 models in my Ruby on Rails 4 app, like this:

```
user has_many orders
order_line belongs to order
```

On the order_lines model, I have a completed flag.

On my user model, how can I make a condition to get only the orders, which has a order line which isn't completed?

I have tried with something like this on my user model:

```
has_many :orders, -> { include :order_lines, where :order_lines => { is_completed: false } }
```

If trying the above I get the error:

```
syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
```

Answer (score 0):

The option to be passed is `includes` and not `include` 
Also there is no method chaining occurring.

Try following

```
has_many :orders, -> { includes(:order_lines).where(:order_lines => { is_completed: false }) }
```

Comment: I tried it but are getting: I do however get an error when trying with: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table order_lines. I don't know if it is because I in my order_lines model have set self.table_name = 'ord_lines'?

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleaner approach would be to add a scope in the order model. Below code might work for you,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :orders
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :lines

    scope :incomplete, -> {
        includes(:lines).
        where("lines.is_completed = ?", false).
        references(:lines)
    }
end

class Line < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order
end
```

And the call to get user's incomplete orders,

```
user = User.first
user.orders.incomplete
```

Also, I think it's better if the name of the column is either status:String or completed:boolean instead of is_complete.

Comment: In This case I never wants to get completed order lines out, otherwise I would agree with you. I do however get an error when trying with: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table order_lines.